# Updating the elements of a vector containing polymorphic instances in Rust

Tags: rust, polymorphism

I am trying to use polymorphism in Rust but am having great difficulties. Here are my basic structures:

```
trait Constant { ... }
struct ConstantString { ... }
impl Constant for ConstantString { ... }
struct ConstantClass { ... }
impl Constant for ConstantClass { ... }
// other Constant implementations

struct JavaClass
    constants: Vec<Box<dyn Constant>>
```

First, I cannot manage to downcast say a `Constant` to a `ConstantString`, even when using `match`.

Also, I cannot manage to go through the constants and initialize them, especially as they reference each other, so each initialization needs to go through the `constants` vector. I tried various versions of the following inside a `JavaClass` method:

```
for constant in self.constants.iter_mut() {
    constant.init(&self);
}
```

to no avail, as I am hitting multiple borrow or immutable borrow errors.

But am I even using the right approach? Rust is behaving very differently than other languages when it comes to memory management.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `std::any::Any`. However, there are a LOT of things going on here, and I wonder if this might not be the best approach when it comes to Rust. Can you explain a bit more about what the bigger problem is that you are trying to solve?

Comment: The bigger problem is that I'm trying to write some code which parses Java bytecode. And that bytecode contains an array of constants which can refer each others (e.g. a Class constant contains the index number of a String constant). So a first pass is creating the vector of constants, the second pass is to resolve these references between constants. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah I see. Part of the problem here is that Rust won’t let you move a struct while immutable references to it exist, and won’t let you create a self referential struct without pinning. Honestly here the best thing might either be to allocate on the heap and use reference counting with `Rc`, or maybe just use a hash table. The hash table method is probably simplest and best. If you don’t know what to use as a key, you can probably just use a counter starting at 0.

Comment: As for downcasting, you probably either want an enum or `Any` as I mentioned before. Personally I would go with an enum, though each has its pros and cons (storage space, storage location, indirection, etc)

Comment: By going with an enum, do you mean use a single struct, contain all the necessary fields for all possible cases and use an enum to determine each other apart?

Comment: I mean create an enum where each item corresponds to a type of constant. Something like: `enum Constant { String(ConstantString), Class(ConstantClass), … }`. Honestly now that I reconsider I am not sure which would be better in this case, trait objects or an enum. I wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

After some further tries, here's how I worked it out. First of all, I got rid of the `Constant` trait and created a collection for each subtype, e.g.

```
pub struct JavaClass {
    constants_class: HashMap<usize, ConstantClass>,
    constants_string: HashMap<usize, ConstantString>,
    constants_string_ref: HashMap<usize, ConstantStringRef>,
    constants_method: HashMap<usize, ConstantMethod>,
    constants_field: HashMap<usize, ConstantField>,
    constants_name_type: HashMap<usize, ConstantNameType>
}
```

Also, by building those inside the `JavaClass` constructor I was able to avoid any mutable error. I found it was easier to manipulate collections declared locally than if they belong to `self`.